# How to plot a gradient color line?

Tags: python, matplotlib

This code plots a `scatterplot` with gradient colors:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(30)
y = x
t = x

plt.scatter(x, y, c=t)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

[image]

but how would I plot a gradient color `line` with a `x` and `y` coordinate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you already have a look at
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/multicolored_line.html?

---

**EDIT:** as suggested in the comments, a minimal working example could be

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

x    = np.linspace(0,1, 100)
y    = np.linspace(0,1, 100)
cols = np.linspace(0,1,len(x))

points = np.array([x, y]).T.reshape(-1, 1, 2)
segments = np.concatenate([points[:-1], points[1:]], axis=1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
lc = LineCollection(segments, cmap='viridis')
lc.set_array(cols)
lc.set_linewidth(2)
line = ax.add_collection(lc)
fig.colorbar(line,ax=ax)
```

[image]

Comment: yes but I can't seem to get it to work on a simple line

Comment: Simple lines in matplotlib, i.e. Line2d-objects, only support one color at once. If you want to have a color gradient, you will need to work with LineCollections.

Comment: The technique is to mesh the line into small pieces and plot each with a color. The provided link shows how it works indeed.